# Accessing the API sublinks

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

```
componentDidMount = () => {
fetch('https://api.teleport.org/api/urban_areas/?embed=ua:item/ua:images')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log(data)
  this.setState({
    images: data
  })
  console.log(this.state.images._embedded)
})
```

}

I am currently a student and working on a project that reads data from an api and writes it to the page. I am trying to get to the part of this api where I can get a url to some images. Before, I only used apis that are very simple to work with and have always used dot notation to get in the data and the and inner parts of it. So far, I got to that '_embedded' part using dot notation, 'data._embedded'. But I can't figure out how to get in that part that says 'ua:item'. I eventually need to get to the 'mobile' part to get to the image url. This is a React project by the way, if it makes any difference for this particular issue.

[image]

Comment: I also shared the screeen shot of the result of request https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq5s2.png

Comment: _embedded["ua:item"][0]. _embedded["ua:item"].photos[0].image.mobile

Comment: It's hard to help you debug your code if we cant' see your code.

Comment: I just added the code to the post, I am just trying it with console.log right now to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @sissonb this sytax is working, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In cases when you have weird stuff as they key-values in JSON, you can use the square brackets like so:

```
JSON.parse('{this:{is-a{JSON:"jsonstring"}}')["this"]["is-a"].JSON
```

yields: jsonstring

Whenever you get square brackets (an array) that has only one item, the index is 0, and you can use the array notation again: `[0]`

in your case:

```
 componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch('https://api.teleport.org/api/urban_areas/?embed=ua:item/ua:images')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
          this.setState({
            images: data
          })
          console.log(this._embedded["ua:item"][0]. _embedded["ua:item"].photos[0].image.mobile)
        })
      }
```

Comment: No problem! You can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark, or upvote by clicking the up button on the side! Doing so rewards people that answer questions, and helps people that come later to check which answer should be viewed.